# Error 403 al iniciar aplicación

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis

Tengo una aplicación en visual studio 2010 y cuando la inicio me funciona perfectamente. Se me abre en la página:

http://localhost:59584/Expectra.GAC.WebApp/

Pero cuando abro la misma en Visual Studio 2017 no me funciona y me da este error:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
El servidor web está configurado para no mostrar una lista los contenidos de este directorio.
```

No sé por que no me funciona bien, por mucho que busco y pruebo no funciona.

gracias!

Comment: Por un lado, el titulo de tu pregunta habla de un error 404, cuando el error es realidad un 403. Por otro lado, mira a ver si la ruta que intenta abrir vs 2017 es lo misma que vs 2010. Si no es asi, prueba a, con la aplicacion ejecutandose, copiar la ruta `http://localhost:59584/Expectra.GAC.WebApp/` en el navegador

Comment: Hola Pikoh, la ruta que pone es: http://localhost:59584 y da ese error si fuerzo la ruta de servidor : http://localhost:59584/Expectra.GAC.WebApp/ me da este otro error: unable to start debugging on the web server. unable to connect t the remote server

Comment: Revisa la página inicial, como index.html, index.asp, default.asp, default.aspx etc.  Si no esté, va a recibir 403.

Comment: Existen, pero si cargo esas páginas el error es que entonces no me carga la página .css